# Two lines of three evenly spaced divs/containers

Tags: css, html, containers, centering

Everything I've tried on my own so far has ended in complete failure.
EXAMPLE: http://broadleafdesign.ca/index-broken-on-purpose-.html
This looks perfectly fine, centered perfectly on my monitor at fullscreen in Chrome.  Any other monitor, or size of the browser window, off centers the paragraphs.

How do I go about making these paragraphs resemble this picture, the arrows representing whitespace?

Note: I'd like the containers/divs to be centered, though the picture I made doesn't represent that very well:

[image]

Comment: Try using a table, perhaps. (I haven't tried this yet, but I suppose it might work). https://www.google.com/#q=html+table

Comment: oh my... divs in spans? the <center> tag? <div align="center">? Display inline-block but position absolute? might want to start here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Comment: @Keeg in my original code, I already have all those things implemented.  The suggestion by user3101289 has helped with this as the issue is likely caused by my mixing of percentages and pixels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evenly space a gallery of images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655396/evenly-space-a-gallery-of-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some basic CSS from an example that I put up for you on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pm56t/

A basic way to achieve this layout would be to declare the widths of the 3 elements as 33.333%, then add float:left. Pad to taste..

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}
.box {
    float:left;
    width:33.333%;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining the margins and div elements as percentages might also work.